# Groovy > Where is the documentation for execute(..) with parameters?

Tags: groovy

Where is the documentation for the `execute(..)` method with parameters?

[I can't find any official documentation.](http://groovy-lang.org/groovy-dev-kit.html#process-management) (**N.B.** I'm not looking to use [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html)).

Here is the example usage:

```
def sb = new StringBuilder()
def proc = ['cmd','/c','echo %AAA%'].execute(["AAA=XXX", "BBB=YYY"], null)
// def proc = ['/bin/bash','-c','echo $AAA'].execute(["AAA=XXX", , "BBB=YYY"], null)
proc.consumeProcessOutput(sb, sb)
proc.waitForOrKill(5000)
println sb.toString() // -> XXX
```

[This nabble post](http://www.groovy-lang.org/mailing-lists.html#nabble-td361438), alludes to being able to pass a String array of `key=value` pairs...

```
ENV = [:] 
ENV.MYVAR = 'Foo Bar' 
ENV.X = 'Baz' 

String[] ENVtoArray() { ENV.collect { k, v -> "$k=$v" } } 

ENVtoArray() 
==> 
{"MYVAR=Foo Bar", "X=Baz"} 

"bash -c set".execute(ENVtoArray(), null).text 
==>
```

**GroovyVersion:** 2.4.5

#### UPDATE**:

Got previous example working, by adding the `cmd /c`. Changing question to "Where is the documentation for the `execute(..)` method (with parameters).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Where is the documentation for the execute(..) method with parameters?

At http://www.groovy-lang.org/gdk.html.

In particular, see http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/String.html#execute(java.lang.String[],%20java.io.File) and http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/List.html#execute(java.lang.String[],%20java.io.File).

Comment: Looks like that's it.

Comment: @NickGrealy Agreed.